# APUE:how to print something alternately in two process?

Tags: c, unix

```
#include<apue.h>
#include<signal.h>

static void charatatime(char *str)
{
    char *ptr;
    int c;
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    for (ptr = str;(c = *ptr++) != 0;)
        putc(c,stdout);
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int i;
    TELL_WAIT();

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_sys("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {

        for (i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        {
            WAIT_PARENT();
            charatatime("ouput from child\n");
        }

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {

        for (i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        {
            charatatime("output from parent\n");
            TELL_CHILD(pid);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it works correctly by only print two times without any loops.but it seems terrible when i
try to print more times with `for` loop....... I think parent process should wait child process after `TELL_CHILD(pid)` finished....

Comment: Use some semaphore or Mutex for synchronization ...

Comment: You could try named semaphores. See e.g. [`sem_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_open.html).

Comment: Have each thread write to a different message queue, then read each message queue in whatever order you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that after the write the parent does not wait for the child to take over.
So your code only makes sure that the child will write after the parent has written at least once.

I can't test the code so check for errors, but maybe something like this will work:

```
#include<apue.h>
#include<signal.h>

static void charatatime(char *str)
{
    char *ptr;
    int c;
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    for (ptr = str;(c = *ptr++) != 0;)
        putc(c,stdout);
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int i;
    TELL_WAIT();

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_sys("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        TELL_PARENT();

        for (i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        {
            WAIT_PARENT();
            charatatime("ouput from child\n");
            TELL_PARENT();
        }

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {

        for (i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        {
            WAIT_CHILD(pid);
            charatatime("output from parent\n");
            TELL_CHILD(pid);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```